# Why does this definition capture the notion of anticommutativity intuitively?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

My textbook (Amann and Escher, *Analysis 1*) defines an operation $\circledast$ (i.e. a function $\circledast: X \times X \to X$) as *anticommutative* if it obeys

1. There is a right identity element $r:=r_X$, that is, $\exists r \in X: x\circledast r=x, x \in X$, and
2. $x \circledast y = r \iff (x \circledast y) \circledast (y \circledast x) = r \iff x = y, \forall x,y$.

Since this definition came up in an exercise (which I've since solved), not much elaboration was given by the authors. My questions are:

1. How does this generalize our intuitive notion of anticommutative?
2. Why is it defined in terms of a right inverse in particular? I suppose a left inverse would be suitable too?

Comment: I don't see the connection.  The cross product doesn't have a right inverse, for example.

Comment: I agree so perhaps there is no connection? But the name in the definition was suggestive... I suppose a better question is, *does* this capture our intuitive notion of anticommutative? @lulu

Comment: I don't see how this is linked to commutativity.  The key point appears to be that every element is its own inverse.  That property can be true (or false) regardless of whether the operation is commutative.  For instance, in any field of characteristic $2$, this holds with respect to the usual addition.

Comment: For groups, if every element is its own inverse, the group is abelian.  Indeed, $xyxy=e\implies yx= xyxyyx=xy$. For whatever that's worth.  Of course, it's not clear that your operation is intended to be associative (probably not, I'd guess).

Comment: Yes, I agree, I am very confused @lulu I suppose I'll have to wade deeper into the book and perhaps at some point some more concrete definition will be connected to this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit hard to relate directly to general anticommutativity, but it is fairly parallel  to how $x\star y=x-y$ would work. Clearly, $r$ is the replacement for $0$, i.e. $ x \star r = x-0 =x$. And $x \star y = r$ is $x - y =0$ is $x=y$; and of course $(x \star y) \star (y \star x) = (x-y) - (y-x) = 2(x-y)$ which is zero iff $x=y$ iff $(x \star y) =r$ (so no characteristic 2).

Constructing this set of rules from anticommutativity is messier. You want $(x \star y) =- (y \star x)$, but then you need a unary $-$. What is that? It's the thing for which $x + (-x)=0$. Well, now you need $0$ and binary $+$. Zero is ok, it's that $r$ for which $ x \star r =x$ for all $x$ (and we get our first rule above). But the binary plus is not great; you could use $x+y = x \star (-y)$. But that's back to needing unary minus.

One issue is that, as was pointed out, these rules don't hold for general anticommutative operations, $\vec{v} \times \vec{w} =0 $ does not imply $\vec{v} = \vec{w}$. So one should not expect to recover these rules from a general anticommutativity.  It seems to really be more of a $x\star y = x-y$ type of deal. But then you can encode that in various ways.

Comment: Lovely answer, thanks so much! Quick question...what's the deal regarding characteristic 2? (I know the definition at least in the context of fields but don't understand what you're saying here.)

Comment: In characteristic 2, $2(x-y)=0$ always, and does not imply $x=y$.

Comment: Got it, thank you!